# Importing data from database file using SQLITE3 and tabulating the data (Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have been creating a very basic database system using SQLite3 in python, and I am attempting to tabulate the data. The problem is I'm not entirely sure how I would go about importing the data and then tabulating said imported data.

At the moment, my file contains the following values, written in the sql code:

```
db_name = "Clients.db"
sql = """Create table Clients
           (ClientID integer,
           Forename text,
           Surname text,
           Company text,
           Currency text,
           eMail text,
           Phone integer,
           Date_Added text,
           primary key(ClientID))"""
create_table(db_name,"Clients",sql)
```

This has successfully saved as a .db file which I can access and have successfully edited with other functions within my program. I can export the data into the .db file, however I have no idea how tabulate it once I run it back through the program. Any advice on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to query a database?

Comment: I suppose so. I need to know how to import data from a database using sql, like this
`def get_all_data(data):
        with sqlite3.connect("Clients.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "select * from Clients where ClientID = ?"
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            db.commit()
            return(data)`
but use the data it returns and format it into a table.

Comment: So you know how to query the database, you've got the data, surely all you need to do is loop through it?

Comment: It's more the fact that I am unsure of how to loop it through, removing the individual data strings, and formatting them into a table. Sort of new to tabulating so I'm not sure how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Thanks by the way, you kinda informed me that I worded my question badly.

Comment: If your problem is the tabular output from Python, this is a duplicate of [Python: Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data)